# Show ads on ajax pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, ads

I have ajax build website where all the pages are generated inside the main page(s). I was trying to put some ads (not adsense ) 
For example amazon native , media net or adcash. When I place the code ad does not show on the pages, even after page/site refresh. I can see in the source code, the script is there. Maybe javascript on ajax is the problem... idk... Any solutions?

Comment: ajax is just a method to send requests to url, you don't build website with ajax, share the code so we can see what you do wrong

Comment: Its some cms I found on codecanyon called bemusic, cant share link as I'm not allowed to post it.

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do is place the ads code in a separate html file and load it externally.

For instance. create and name a div and load it as such with jquery or javascript

**HTML**

```
<div id="thediv"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#thediv').load("url/ads.html")
```

**Javascript**

```
function load_ads() {
 document.getElementById("#thediv").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="url/ads.html" ></object>';
}
```